# How to interact other android app with the help of Uri?

Tags: android, affiliates

I am currently working on a project for affiliate Marketing.

Recently, I came across a problem. For affiliate Marketing I have to open a affiliate Url for certain products in site like [Amazon](http://amazon.in), [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com) and [Snapdeal](http://www.snapdeal.com). I think there is no smart Url(Not Sure) for snapdeal and amazon, but for flipkart there is affiliate Link [here](http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/tracking_mobile_devices_info). Summary, the links are:-

- Home page- http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/?affid=myAffiliateId
- Offers page- http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/offers?affid=myAffiliateId
- Category pages- http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/computers/laptops?sid=6bo,b5g&affid=myAffiliateId
- Product pages- http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/nike-dewired-premium-sneakers/p/itmdzthskkpuquue?pid=SHODZAR2PD9YKHRH&affid=myAffiliateId

This links are valid because I tested it yesterday. But today this links are not redirecting me to the flipkart android app but redirecting to the flipkart website(Opening in android Google chrome). My question is why the behavior is not uniform? And whether there is any link for amazon affiliate marketing samrt url for opening amazon mobile app?

Thanks in Advance.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/?affid=myAffiliateId");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```